# MediaRecorder.stop() hangs on Samsung Galaxy Camera

Tags: android, freeze, mediarecorder

Calling `stop()` on my MediaRecorder hangs indefinitely on the Samsung Galaxy Camera. Placing this call in a separate thread does not help the problem either.

Logcat does not show any error messages. However, running this same app does not incur any problems on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

This is the code surrounding my call to `stop`:

```
View.OnClickListener captureListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder
            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            captureButton.setText("Capture");
            isRecording = false;
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                // inform the user that recording has started
                captureButton.setText("Stop");
                isRecording = true;
            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I saw is that for some devices MediaRecorder.stop() hangs if there is no preview attached (i.e. you called Camera.stopPreview() before or maybe you never called startPreview()).